# How to call @RestControllerAdvice class from a unit test in the Service layer of a REST web service in java?

Tags: java, spring

I have a REST webservice application. I am handling exceptions by exception handler using the annotation  @ExceptionHandler and @RestControllerAdvice. My exceptions are thrown in the Service layer. Now I am writing unit tests for the service layer. I am checking the exceptions using Assert.assertThrows. The exception is thrown, and the test passes. However, the exception handler method is not called when an exception is thrown. I need the exception handler method to be called during the unit test. Test class and the ExceptionHandler class are like the following.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class ServiceTest {

  @InjectMocks
  private Service testService = new ServiceImpl();

  @Mock
  private Repository repository; 
 

  @Test
  public void testException() {
    assertThrows(
        Exception.class, ()->{
          // Code that throws exception.
        });
  }
}

@RestControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionHandler {

  @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
  public ResponseEntity<Object> handleUnknownException(Exception ex) {
    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
               .body("Body Here");
  }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**@RestControllerAdvice** is kind of interceptor of exceptions thrown by class annotated with @RestController, that's why exception handler method is not being invoked for your test schenario.

To test that, you should write a test for your the controller, Use the mockMvc and register your exceptionHandler class with it like below. hope, it helps.

```
this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(new YourController()).setControllerAdvice(ExceptionHandler.class)
                .build();
```

Answer (score 0):

[Very late answer] You don't need to explicitly call your `@RestControllerAdvice` as it will be called as soon as an exception is rised in your code. You should try to handle your exception this way:

```
@GetMapping("/personality")
public ResponseEntity<Response> computePersonality(@Valid @RequestBody Dto dto) throws BadRequestException {
    try {
            // any other mapping or code
            var response = yourService.yourMethod(dto);
            // any other mapping or code
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(response);
    } catch (NumerologyValidationException exception) {
        throw new BadRequestException("An error occurs...", exception);
    }
}
```

Here, your controller only understand HTTP Code response and all your exception should be redirect to the `@RestControllerAdvice`.
Check this [link](https://mathieu.fenniak.net/the-api-checklist/) for more details about **4XX** and **5XX** error code management.